# laravel querying multiple classes and or tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How do I query more than two tables. What I want to do is have a list of products queryed by a genre and then query productvariations - where a product variation has a producttype_id = $producttype->id

```
Route::get('browse/{producttype_slug}/{genre_slug}', array(
    'as' => 'products.viewbygenre', 
    function($productype_slug, $genre_slug) 
    {       
        $producttype = ProductTypes::where('slug', '=', $productype_slug)->firstOrFail();

        $genre = GenreTypes::where('slug', '=', $genre_slug)->firstOrFail();

        // error below
        $products = Product::with(array('ProductVariations', 'GenreTypes'))
         ->where('genre', '=', $genre->id)->get();

        return View::make('products.viewbygenre')->with(compact('productvariations', 'genre', 'producttype'));

}))->where('producttype_slug', '[A-Za-z\-]+')->where('genre_slug', '[A-Za-z\-]+');
```

products class

```
class Product extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = "products";
    protected $fillable = ['keywords', 'description', 'title', 'slug', 'release_date', 'clip'];

    public function productvariations() {
        return $this->hasMany("ProductVariations");
    }

    public function variations() {
        $variations = $this->productvariations()->get();
        return $variations;
    }


    public function genres() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('GenreTypes', 'product_genretypes', 'product_id', 'genretype_id')->withTimestamps();
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the issue so I will just refer to this bit:

```
// error below
$products = Product::with(array('ProductVariations', 'GenreTypes'))
         ->where('genre', '=', $genre->id)->get();
```

I believe you cannot use a where clause this way on a 'with' array. I am not 100% sure if this works when you have more than one parameter in your with method but this is worth trying:

```
$products = \Product::with(array('ProductVariations', 'GenreTypes' => function ($query)
    {
        // Note I think you also had a mistake in your column name 
        // (genre should be genretype_id?)
        // Also ... not sure how you are getting the $genre->id variable 
        // as I cannot see the the $genre object / collection in this method you provided !
        $query->where('genretype_id', '=', $genre->id);
    }))->get();
```

Let us know how you get on.